# Remove XML header using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, afnetworking

I'm currently getting my data on web using `AFNetworking` using the code below. My problem is, the `responseObject` comes with XML header tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

Is there a way to request using `AFNetworking` without these tags? I know that this can be done on `NSString`, but I don't think it's the correct way. Thanks!

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is my URL"]];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil 
success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Wilson: %@", error);
    return;
}];
```

Comment: If you wish to parse the XML, the header needs to be there otherwise it won't be valid XML.

Comment: I won't be parsing the said XML after this, @rmaddy

Comment: It you simply want to treat the XML as a plain old string then you need to write code to remove whatever part of the string that you don't want.

Comment: If there is no other solution, then yes. I'm trying to find out if there is a better way on approaching the task.

Comment: There isn't. What you want to do is very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove this chunk of response, Here I wrote a regex that removes it.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is my URL"]];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil
   success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

     NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSString *pattern = @"(<\\?xml.*\\?>)";
     NSError *error = NULL;
     NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];

     NSString *newString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString: string
                                                      options: 0
                                                        range: NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                                 withTemplate: @""];
     NSLog(@"the response without XML Header is: %@", newString);

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Wilson: %@", error);
        return;
 }];
```

I hope these code will be useful for your issue.

Comment: Can you explain how this results in an XML result but without the standard `<?xml ... ?>` header line?

Comment: Oh Sorry, It was a misunderstanding, I changed my answer please check it again. Thanks ;)